# Why the different wing and tail designs in similar sized jets vs turbo prop?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-design, dash-8

I was flying on [Porter Airlines](http://www.flyporter.com) and they had an info card about how similar the Bombardier (I still say DeHavilland) Dash 8 Q400s are to the [Bombardier CSeries](http://cseries.com) they have ordered.

There was a cool overlay photo to show relative sizes and shapes:

[image: Dash 8 vs CSeries]

Looking at that image, it got me wondering about the straight vs angled wing.  Straight vs angled tails, etc.

I get that a jet is faster than a turbo prop.

Cseries cruise speeds are:
Mach 0.78 (828 km/h, 447 kn, 514 mph)

Dash8 Q400 cruise speeds are:
414 mph (667 km/h) 360 knots

Those are pretty close and yet that is a pretty radical wing design change.

Is this just the history an old design (Dash 8) vs a very modern design?

Comment: Hint: M.60 is quite different from M.82. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, for starters, the speeds are actually pretty significantly different. The Cseries is almost 25% faster than the Q400. Swept airfoils are much more efficient at those higher speeds, as are jet engines.

The Q400 is also a wildly stretched version of the original DeHavilland Canada DHC-8 (Dash 8), which was itself based on the 4-engine DHC-7 (Dash 7) STOL airliner. DHC has a lot of history building short takeoff and landing aircraft with pretty extreme performance, and a lot of that colored the design of the Dash 8. What you see today in the Q400 is the result of about 70 years of backcountry aircraft design, applied to a commuter airliner.

The Cseries, on the other hand, is a clean-sheet Bombardier design meant to compete with the E-jets and the smallest 737s (and 717).

Hopefully that answers your questions!

Comment: For some more info on why swept wings tend to show up as you get above about mach 0.7 or so, [check out the Wikipedia article on swept wings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swept_wing#Subsonic_and_transonic_behavior). You'll even find a reference there to a swept-wing transsonic propeller driven aircraft - the [TU-95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu-95) which has a top speed around the same as the C series,

Comment: Even more fun, the [Tu-114 airliner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-114) was based on the Bear and could carry up to 225 passengers. They're pretty absurdly fast turboprops, and I think their engines are some of the most powerful in the world.

Comment: As I recall they're also allegedly one of the loudest aircraft in operation - I've never had the pleasure of listening to one take off, but judging by the size of that propeller disk it would not surprise me if this were true.

Comment: @voretaq7 Isn't the noise caused by the tips going supersonic rather than the size *per se*? (Sure, longer blades mean that the tips will go supersonic at lower rpm.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yup - and that's the reason large blades are potentially noisier (it's harder to balance "efficient RPM for the airfoil" with "please don't be making sonic booms"). You also get a larger "whoosh" as each blade goes by (moving comparatively more air than a smaller-diameter prop at the same RPM), but i's the noise off the tips that tends to dominate.